# Reading from csv file Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to solve this problem.
I am reading data from csv fiile which has the following columns:

```
id, name, price
```

So i use the following code to read the csv:

```
import sys
import csv as input

def readFile(path):
    try:
        finput = input.reader(open(path,'rb'),delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
    except IOError as (errno,strerror):
            print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno,strerror)
    except:
            print "Unexpected Error: ",sys.exc_info()[0]
            raise
    # covert format into list
    fmod = list(finput)
    return fmod
```

but the problem is the name field can be like

name, item_det
now that " , " creates a trouble for me..
instead of reading the name field as a single entity having a comma in the description..
it splits that particular field.
How do I solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Read the file in a line at a time (no delimiter) and look at one of the python regex functions with more advanced features to split the string into fields

Comment: Normally, your CSV file would then have quotes in it, so that a line would be `|name, item_det|, other_field, another_field` (since you set `quotechar='|'`). The CSV module can handle that. If not, you'll probably want to do like @MartinBeckett said and parse it manually, or check the length of the list and merge those two fields manually if necessary.

Comment: do you have a control over the csv input file creation or you are forced to deal with broken csv files? usually people use `quotechar='"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is exactly that: "Comma Separated". You either need to quote the name field:

```
|name,item_det|
```

Or use an escape character, but you have to turn it on by setting quoting to QUOTE_NONE:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(path, "rb"), delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="\\")
```

Example:

```
name\,item_det
```

Otherwise, don't use the csv module.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that any single values that contain your delimiter char (`,`) are enclosed in the `quotechar` (`|`, in your example). Thus, any time the `name` field in a row is of the form `<name>, <item_det>` the row should read something like `... ,|<name>, <item_det>|, ...`.